# Gradle build jar with dependencies

Tags: android, jar, gradle, android-studio, aar

I'm developing Android library for applications. I'm using Gradle system and Android Studio to build *.aar file. Now I need to build *.jar file to give it to developers who are working with eclipse. I need to build *.jar file from my project and add all *.jar dependencies from `libs/` to this *.jar. And I think also Android Manifest file. How to build such *.jar file with all dependencies using Grdale? Thanks.

Comment: A JAR file does not contain an `AndroidManifest.xml` file. It also cannot contain any assets or resources used by your AAR file. Distribute the Android library project itself to your Eclipse developers.

Comment: @CommonsWare But it's not safe, he can to do with my source code all what he wants, isn't it?

Comment: Either ship the Android library project, or rewrite your library to be a pure JAR (no manifest/resources/assets), or do not support Eclipse users. There is no well-supported recipe for creating a binary-only Android library project, and since Google dropped Eclipse support, I doubt that there will be such a recipe. Also, "add all *.jar dependencies from libs/ to this *.jar" is not a good practice, as now you are adding hidden libraries to the classpath and are preventing the developer from using new versions of those libraries (e.g., with bug fixes).